# How can I download json file from S3 using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a folder in S3 bucket that contains json files. I am using Spring Boot. The user provides `folder name` and specific  file(`json file`) name.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> downloading(String folderName, String fileName) throws IOException {
    S3Object s3Object = s3client
            .getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3BucketName, folderName + fileName));
    if (s3Object.getKey().length() > 0) {
      //enables the user to dowload json file
      //return the object that can be dowloaded, status code 
      return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else{
      //return error message and status code 
      return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have referred the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578937/spring-boot-amazon-aws-s3-bucket-file-download-access-denied/48709151).

**So, I have added just a part of the code that will help you :**

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloading(String folderName, String fileName) {
    S3Object s3Object = s3client
            .getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3BucketName, folderName + fileName));
    if (s3Object.getKey().length() > 0) {
      S3ObjectInputStream input = s3Object.getObjectContent();
      byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
      String file = URLEncoder.encode(s3Object.getKey(), "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      headers.setContentLength(bytes.length);
      headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", file);
      return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, HttpStatus.OK);
    } 
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: can you explain your solution?